# Proving that a regular language is closed under a unique definition of 'reverse'

Tags: automata, regular-language, finite-automata

Heyy guys, I was given the next question in one of my homework assignments and I can't quite figure out how to approach it. I'd really appreciate some help with it. Thank you!  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've been given a question like this, you've probably seen some closure properties of regular languages.  In particular, you may know that regular languages are closed under union, intersection, complementation, reversal, substitutions, and homomorphisms.

Some of these closure properties are usually proved by showing how to build an automaton that accepts the transformed language; others are proved by showing how to write a regular expression for the transformed language.

A classic example of the latter type of proof is the one for closure under substitutions.  If $\mu$ is a map from alphabet $\Sigma$ to the regular languages over alphabet $\Gamma$, and $r$ is a regular expression over $\Sigma$, then replacing every letter $\sigma$ in $r$ with a regular expression for $\mu(\sigma)$ yields the desired regular expression.

In the case of $\operatorname{Inv}(L) = \{\, xyz : xy^Rz \in L \,\}$, though, we must be able to replace an arbitrary subword of a word in $L$ with its reversal; an arbitrary subword may not be produced by a proper subexpression of the chosen regular expression for $L$ that we may reverse.  For example, if $L = 0^*1^*$, we have that $00111001 \in \operatorname{Inv}(L)$ because $00001111 \in L$, and it's not clear how to manipulate $0^*1^*$ to get $0^*1^*0^*1^*$ or something equivalent.

So we turn to the other master technique for the proof of closure properties, namely the construction of an automaton for $\operatorname{Inv}(L)$ from an automaton for $L$.  After all, this is the technique used to prove closure of regular languages under reversal, and the problem at hand shouldn't be too different.

Let's recall how we deal with reversal: given an $A_L$ that accepts $L$, we build an automaton $A_{L^R}$ that accepts $L^R$ by reversing the directions of all transitions and swapping initial and accepting states.  If our definition of automata does not allow multiple initial states, we'll add a new initial state and a few $\epsilon$-transitions.

Let's see now what simple facts we know about $\operatorname{Inv}(L)$.  Since $y$ may be the empty word, we have that $L \subseteq \operatorname{Inv}(L)$.  Likewise, since $x$ and $z$ may be the empty word, we have that $L^R \subseteq \operatorname{Inv}(L)$.  These inclusions suggest that we may use the automata for $L$ and $L^R$ as building blocks for the automaton that accepts $\operatorname{Inv}(L)$, connecting them with $\epsilon$-transitions.

I'll pause here, to give you a chance to finish the construction yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much Fabio! Are you saying that in order to build a NFA for this language I must have a few starting states which involve all of those case? (the last part of what you've written)

Comment: No, I didn't mean to suggest that.  I meant that you build an NFA by combining copies of the automata for $L$ and $L^R$.  One copy is the initial copy and has the overall initial state.  From one copy you can skip to the next by taking an $\epsilon$-transition.  One copy reads $x$, the second reads $y$, and the third reads $z$.

Comment: Oh..I see! amazing! Thanks Fabio =)

Comment: Hello Fabio! I've tried writing it down formally but I fail to do so, there are so many options for the partitions and I can't seem to get it right, It will be very helpful if you could show me atleast a part of the proof :)

Comment: A proof sketch may go like this. Suppose $xy^Rz$ has an accepting run in $A_L$. We show that $xyz$ has an accepting run in  $A_{\operatorname{Inv}(L)}$. Take any accepting run of $xy^Rz$ in $A_L$ and add two $\epsilon$-transitions, one at the end of $x$ and one at the end of $y^R$. Each added transition goes from one component to the next. The resulting run accepts $xyz$ in $A_{\operatorname{Inv}(L)}$. In the other direction, locate the two $\epsilon$-transtions that change components and remove them. To make this formal, let $Q \times \{0,1,2\}$ be the states of the new automaton, etc..

Comment: But doesn't the part where I reverse the string (y) invovle much more states?

Comment: No the derived automaton has three times as many states as the original one.  Try a simple example like $0^*1^*$.  You should get a total of six states.

Comment: For the reversing part, should I use the NFA for reverseL? Or the DFA? Im confused

Comment: Either one, but the NFA is simpler and there's no compelling reason to do otherwise.  In any case, once you add the $\epsilon$-transitions from $(q,0)$ to $(q,1)$ and from $(q,1)$ to $(q,2)$ for all $q \in Q$, you are back to a nondeterministic automaton.  If you wanted a DFA you'd have to determinize again.  For the proof, determinization is unnecessary.